# What function is called to save order comments/status in the backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, order-status

What function is called to save new comments and update the order status, when viewing the order in the backend.

The **addComment** function in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php` looks to be what I need but that's not the case. Altering this function is having no effect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php**

**addCommentAction** is responsible for save comment.

**How to save?**

Go to **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php**, check following code block

```
/*
 * Add a comment to order
 * Different or default status may be specified
 *
 * @param string $comment
 * @param string $status
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History
 */
public function addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status = false)
{
    if (false === $status) {
        $status = $this->getStatus();
    } elseif (true === $status) {
        $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($this->getState());
    } else {
        $this->setStatus($status);
    }
    $history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
        ->setStatus($status)
        ->setComment($comment)
        ->setEntityName($this->_historyEntityName);
    $this->addStatusHistory($history);
    return $history;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate that's exactly what I need. If you're looking for a particular method, how do you go about finding it? If you don't mind me asking